# Looking at modifying a pipeline build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am working for a company that develops a lot of apps and we use Azure devops portal for all of our pipeline releases etc.
So, the general flow is that a developer will create a branch to do the development on and change the code on that branch. They would like to deploy that branch before it is merged back into the development line from a pipeline, rather than from visual studio, which they currently do. So, it's about giving the developer to the option to choose which branch to deploy from.
Has anyone done something similar or point me in the right direction to how I could go about this?

Comment: Hello @DarraghM , have you got a chance to check my post? Appreciated for your feedback on this.

Answer (score 1):

When creating the release, currently there is no build-in feature to choose which branch to deploy from, the release pipeline works with the corresponding source Artifacts configuration.

[image]

A good approach for your scenario is referring to the build id on your build pipeline (instead of release pipeline).

When running the build pipeline, you could choose the target branch and record the **build id** for this run.

[image]

[image]

In your release pipeline, you could check whether the source Artifacts is from your target branch by checking the **build id**.

[image]